# Stack Exchange profile shows zero count before posting any posts on the respective site

Tags: bug, status-completed, information-display, network-profile

The Stack Exchange network profile page showing zero questions and zero answers for all accounts.

[image]

After posting this question, it shows the questions count for Meta Stack Overflow.

[image]

**Now the issue is clear**, I'd posted a question just now on Sports.SE beta site and then I can see the questions count for Sports.SE in my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik?tab=accounts).

We should fix it.

Comment: I'll get the beer!

Comment: Indeed, it has been like this for hours for me. Although, I do have correct values for some stats.

Comment: Weird, it's showing me 62 question and 0 answers for [your profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik?tab=accounts) on [meta-so].

Comment: Y u no use [freehand circles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KXFhOm.jpg)? Really disappointed. :(